# How to make an image viewer like Facebook or Twitter ? iOS

Tags: ios, image, zooming, viewer

I would like to make an image viewer like Facebook or Twitter which user can pinch to zoom and slide up or down to dismiss the current image viewer. When the image press i want it to present a image viewer like facebook which enlarge an become an image viewer. I would like to know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is control you can use: https://github.com/bogardon/GGFullscreenImageViewController

preview video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdKS985eY1Q&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This is right but it does not have slide up or slide down to dismiss the view .

Comment: @KZY you can also take a look at this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cxphotobrowser

Comment: @KZY or search CocoaControls for similar component that suits your needs: https://www.cocoacontrols.com

Comment: exactly what i was keeping for spot on, though it is a legacy code needed some amendments before integration into the project ;)